# K8S schedule pods only after DaemonSets are up

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I would like to have my EKS nodes being able to host new pods only after a particular daemonSet pod is up and running.
If a better way is to schedule pods only after ALL daemonsets are up, I am okay with that.

How should I approach it?

Answer (score 0):

**Option : 1** - Using **InitContainer**

You can use the **initcontainer** with the deployment to check the status of the **Daemon** **set** if not up, your Deployment container won't get started.

```
spec:
      initContainers:
      - name: wait-for-deployment
        image: busybox
        args:
        - /bin/bash
        - -c
        - >
          set -x;
          while [[ "$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w ''%{http_code}'' http://service:8080/)" != "200" ]]; do 
            echo '.'
            sleep 15;
          done
      containers:
```

You can also use the **kubectl** inside the init container to check the status of the **Daemon set**, if not responding to any response when we hit the **HTTP** **request**.

**Option : 2** - Using **Jobs**

You can use the Jobs to check the status of **Daemon set** and once those are **up** & **running** Job will scale up the deployment PODs or run the command to create the deployment.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a taint on your nodes to prevent scheduling of pods except the daemonset that has to have the corresponding toleration. A container in your daemonset (sidecar or init-container) could call the API to remove the taint from the node so that from that point any pod can be scheduled on it.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/